# Crashing upon passing array by reference in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to pass an array to a function in C. I know you cannot do this by value, and only by pointer.

So far I have made sure that my array (intInput) is declared outside of main(void) to ensure it's scope is correct, but when I run the program, it crashes upon getting to the line:

```
printf("%d", intInput[u]);
```

I suspect I have messed up the use of pointers here, specifically with the declaration call to the function and passing of the parameter. What have I done wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int intInput[16];
int main(void)
{
    // Reference post http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~bartlett/credit_card_number.html
    char strType[20];
    printf("What card type do you want to verify? ");
    scanf("%s", strType);   
    int c;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        printf("Please insert next char: ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
        printf("Character entered: %d \n", c);
        intInput[i] = c;
        printf("Value of i is: %d \n", i);
    }

    mastercard(intInput[16]);
}

void mastercard(int intInput[])
{
    // Prefix 51-55, Length 16, Check Digit Algorithm MOD 10
    int u, intTotalAlternate;
    u = 15;
    intTotalAlternate = 0;
    puts("GOT THIS FAR");
    while (u > 1)
    {
        printf("%d", intInput[u]);
        intTotalAlternate += (intInput[u]);
        printf("value %d \n", (intInput[u]));
        u -= 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare `intInputs`?

Comment: No such thing as a reference in C

Comment: `i <= 15` should be `i < 16`

Comment: @EdHeal: the canonical way is `for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)` but the code above is correct in this particular line

Comment: @png - You'r right - bit too early in the morning. will edit

Comment: you should use `%20s` for your `scanf` format to avoid buffer overflow

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: the specifier should be `%19s` as you need space for the `'\0'` terminator which `scanf` does not count.

Comment: @pmg I actually edited my comment *from* that so somebody would tell me whether `scanf` *did* count the null terminator haha

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: lol, nice. Now you know.

Answer (score 5):

```
mastercard(intInput[16]);
```

`intInput[16]` does not exist.
Also it would be a value of type `int` which is not compatible with what the function expects.

Turn ON all compiler warnings and **mind them**.

Comment: Is it not declared at the top of the program (int intInput[16];), or have I done that wrong?

Comment: `intInput` is an array. Its 16 elements go from `intInput[0]` to `intInput[15]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `mastercard` like this :

```
mastercard(intInput);
```

`mastercard` expects an array of ints, but you are passing it an int, the one at position 16 of `intInput`, rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying with that code to do, or what exactly are you expecting to do, but your program should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int intInput[16];

void mastercard(int *intInput){
    int u, intTotalAlternate;
    u = 15;
    intTotalAlternate = 0;
    puts("GOT THIS FAR");
    while (u > 1)
    {
        printf("%d", intInput[u]);
        intTotalAlternate += (intInput[u]);
        printf("value %d \n", (intInput[u]));
        u -= 2;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int c,i;
    char strType[20];
    printf("What card type do you want to verify? ");

    if ((scanf("%19s", strType)) != EOF)


    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)    {
        printf("Please insert next char: ");
        if ((scanf("%d", &c)) != EOF)

        printf("Character entered: %d \n", c);
        intInput[i] = c;
        printf("Value of i is: %d \n", i);
    }

    mastercard(intInput);
}
```

> printf("Please insert next char: ");

Are you sure that you need int c and not char c ?

Answer (score 0):

Noone said anything about it so a question occured to me:

When he uses a global variable, why should he use a pointer?
He can access it anywhere anyway, because he used a global variable, which should normally not be done afaik. Or am I missing something?

Anyway a standard tutorial on arrays and pointers would help you OP.

Comment: You are right: using both a global and a pointer to that global (hiding the global) is unnecessarily complicating the program.